# cakephp not load phpwois

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm using cakephp and phpwhois
I'm copying **phpwhois** folder in **app/vendor**
in my controller :

```
App::import('Vendor', 'phpWhois\Whois', array('file' => 'phpWhois/Whois.php'));
```

**whois** class is extended with **whpisclient** class
and show me this error :

```
Error: Class 'phpWhois\WhoisClient' not found   
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\padweb\app\Vendor\phpWhois\Whois.php
```

If I use composer autoloader, it shows me the same error.

Comment: YOu need to provide more information

Comment: phpwhois : https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois

Answer (score 0):

see this nice article http://ceeram.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/using-composer-with-cakephp-2-dot-x/
about using composer in cakephp 2.0
it will allow you to use a global autoload.php file for all your new packages that you install with composer

let me know if it helps